# new RegExp is not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression which validates 3 consecutive digits.

```
/^\d{3}$/.test("12345")  // false
/^\d{3}$/.test("123")    // true
```

How can I transform this regex pattern into a `RegExp` object?

I tried:

```
var re = new RegExp("\\d{3}", "gi");
```

but `re.test("12345")` returns true

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

```
var re = new RegExp("^\\d{3}$", "gi");
```

(I assume the "gi" flag is not really necessary in this case...)

http://jsfiddle.net/GyZqw/

Answer (score 2):

Use this regular expression:

```
^\d{3}$
```

with start and end of line specified.

In JavaScript you should escape `\` char, i.e.:

```
"^\\d{3}$"
```

Comment: Stil not working:  var re = new RegExp("^\d{3}$", "gi");  console.log(re.test("123")); returns false

Comment: @RaraituL, `^\d{3}$` it is regex. Definitely you should escape it in your environment. In JavaScript it would be `^\\d{3}$`.

Answer (score 2):

```
new RegExp("^\\d{3}$", "gi")
```

you forgot ^ and $

Answer (score 1):

```
var re = new RegExp("^\\d{3}$");
```